# Generic DAO interface creation at runtime

Tags: java, generics, proxy, dry

```
public interface  GenericDAO<T>{
   // some methods
}
public interface PersonGenericDAO extends GenericDAO<Person> {}
public interface TeacherGenericDAO extends GenericDAO<Teacher> {}
public interface StudentGenericDAO extends GenericDAO<Student> {}
```

I have a library which is creating proxy instances by these interfaces as this:

```
creator.onDemand(PersonGenericDAO.class);
```

I just want to create a static method to remove unnecessary Interfaces. But I dont have any idea about this.

```
public static <X> GenericDAO<X> getGenericDAO(X type){
   // return ?????????? 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make the parameter a `Class<X>`:

```
public static <X> GenericDAO<X> getGenericDAO(Class<X> type){
   return new HibernateDAO<X>();
}
```

and call it as

```
GenericDao<Person> personDao = getGenericDAO(Person.class);
```

Comment: It is a pity that I am not using Hibernate :)